# Moderators are not able to cancel pending redaction requests

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

Moderators are not able to click the "Cancel" button to withdraw existing redaction requests. The error message "**You may not approve your own redaction**" is displayed, when the expected behaviour is the redaction request withdrawn from the mod flag queue.

See attached screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Win 10, Chrome v80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that `Model.CancelUrl` work a ton better here than `Model.SubmitUrl`. :)

The fix is awaiting deployment with the next prod build. Thanks for the report!